# Result is not Defined "Error" in server logs for a GET request to DB

Tags: express

router.get('/', rejectUnauthenticated, (req, res) => {
console.log('Ticket Info GET');

```
const sqlQuery = `SELECT "question","department","priority" FROM "question_table";`;
// const sqlParams=[req.params.id]
// console.log('Log for sql Params', sqlParams);

pool.query(sqlQuery)
  .then((dbResponse) => {
    console.log('Ticket Details GET',dbResponse);
    res.send(dbResponse.rows);
    console.log('Ticket Details GET');
    
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR: Get all videos', err);
    res.sendStatus(500)
  })
```

});

Comment: Any ideas as to why on earth this is happening?

Comment: Listening on port: 5000
{ question: 'tgb', department: 'Management', priority: 'Medium' }
ReferenceError: result is not defined

Comment: add :id in route like this 
`router.get('/:id', rejectUnauthenticated, (req, res) => {`